# Stuck on evaluating the complex integral $\int_{\gamma}\Big (\frac{z+1}{z}\Big)^n dz$ with $\gamma:[0,2\pi] \to \Bbb C$ and $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Let $\gamma:[0,2\pi] \to \Bbb C$ and $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$.Proof:

$$\int_{\gamma} \Big(\frac{z+1}{z}\Big)^ndz = 2\pi i \cdot n , n \in\Bbb N $$

I've got

$$\begin{align} \int_{\gamma} \Big(\frac{z+1}{z}\Big)^ndz & = \int_{\gamma} \Big(\frac{z+1}{z}\Big)^ndz \\
& = \int_{\gamma} \Big(1+\frac{1}{z}\Big)^ndz \\
& = \int_{\gamma} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\Big(\frac{1}{z}\Big)^kdz \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \int_{\gamma} \binom{n}{k}\Big(\frac{1}{z}\Big)^kdz \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \int_{\gamma} \Big(\frac{1}{z}\Big)^kdz \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-itk}\cdot i \cdot e^{it}dt \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \int_0^{2\pi} i e^{it(1-k)} dt \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \Big[\frac{ie^{it(1-k)}}{(1-k)}\Big]_0^{2\pi}\\ 
& = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{i(e^{-2i\pi k}-1)}{(1-k)}\\ 
\end{align} $$

Now I'm not sure....the Integral is depending on $n$ , so I can't take out the binomial coefficient out of the integral. Any ideas, thoughts, critics, etc ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can take the binomial coefficient out of the integral. The integral is over z and the binomial coefficient only depends on n and k.

Comment: Also notice that $\int_x^y e^{iht}\,dt=\frac1{ih} (e^{ihy}-e^{ihx})$ only works for $h\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way by using Cauchy's integral formula
$$\int_{\gamma}\left(\frac{z+1}{z}\right)^{n} dz=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z+1)^{n}\bigg|_{z=0}=2\pi i\cdot n$$

Comment: Thanks ! Looks a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

Hit this with Cauchy's integral formula, for you, $a=0,n+1=n, f(z)=(z+1)^n$. Thus

\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \bigg(\frac{z+1}{z} \bigg)^ndz&=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!} \bigg(\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}(z+1)^n\bigg\vert_{z=0} \bigg)\\
&=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}n!(1)\\
&=2\pi i n.
\end{align}